# mongodump - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongodump, mongorestore

I'm running mongo 2.6.5 & Ubuntu 14.04

I run the command;

```
mongodump -d MyDBname -o /home/mongobackup
```

and I get the following error;

```
2017-02-12T03:19:44.956+1000 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I'm new to mongo, and all I want to do is take a dump of the 3 DB's and use the `mongorestore` to bring them back up on another server (exact same server expect an image from 3 months ago).

If you could please confirm that would work as well - that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your command as follows and try to run.

```
    mongodump --db MyDBname -o /home/mongobackup
```

Please ensure your Mongo instance is running with a database **MyDBname** and the output directory **/home/mongobackup** exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably executing this command inside mongo cli.
Try this directly on shell.

Do not forget to pass your user and password together.